# Where do I find my public SSH key?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-core

I am trying to do an initial installation of Ubuntu & know almost nothing about making it happen. It asks for an SSH key. Where do I find a public SSH key?

Comment: Ubuntu installation doesn't usually ask for any SSH keys. Which part of the installation is requiring SSH key? Where are you installing Ubuntu? Is it on your local machine or somewhere else?

Comment: Why is it asking for keys? You generally use those to harden a server and need it on a PC connecting to that server. If that is your use-case see my answer :) BUT you made those keys yourself using a key generator and are told what to do so I am a bit curious to the why?

Comment: @Rinzwind AFAIK Ubuntu Core installation requires uploading a ssh public key to the SSO account. Raspberry Pi hardware users are sometimes directed to install Ubuntu Core for their server needs.

Answer (score 2):

To view all keys on an Ubuntu server:

```
ls ~/.ssh/*.pub
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you ask about your own server's public keys they are (as of Ubuntu 22.04) located here:

/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

So doing in your terminal:
cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
or
cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
or
cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

You can view your public keys.

Comment: These are not the ssh public keys needed during Ubuntu Core installation.